# virt-install with Ubuntu server 18 fails with "ERROR Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree."

Tags: server, 18.04, virtualization, kvm-virtualization, minecraft

Hello there (Greenhorn here),

I have a server with Ubuntu 18.04.1 server running on the bare metal. I am attempting to get a VM spun up using virt-install. This works with 14.04 and 16.04, but I get a complete failure attempting to use 18.04 or 18.10. My install is fully updated. I am trying to run some Alpha version software, thus the need for a VM, and it happens to require version 18 (so I am told).

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 18.04.1 LTS
Release:        18.04
Codename:       bionic
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Here is the syntax I use to spin up the VMs. I have 2 VMs running 14.04 with zero issues for a couple months,so those are good. I am not sure what the error is, but I have run wget to get the version 18 ISOs a few times direct from Ubuntu, not sure if it is the ISO that is the issue or not.

Issue with 18.04

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Bedrock Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --os-variant=ubuntu18.04 \
> --ram=2048 \
> --vcpus=2 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-18.04.1-live-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   70 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start Hermes
otherwise, please restart your installation.
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Same error trying 18.10 server

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Bedrock Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --os-variant=ubuntu18.10 \
> --ram=2048 \
> --vcpus=2 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-18.10-live-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   68 B  00:00:00
ERROR    Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree.
Domain installation does not appear to have been successful.
If it was, you can restart your domain by running:
  virsh --connect qemu:///system start Hermes
otherwise, please restart your installation.
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Fine with ZERO issues with 16.04

```
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$ sudo virt-install \
> --name Hermes \
> --description "Bedrock Minecraft VM" \
> --os-type=Linux \
> --os-variant=ubuntu16.04 \
> --ram=2048 \
> --vcpus=2 \
> --disk path=/home/ziggidy/VMs/Drive2/Hermes.img,bus=virtio,size=50 \
> --network bridge:br0 \
> --graphics none \
> --location /home/ziggidy/ISOs/ubuntu-16.04.5-server-amd64.iso \
> --extra-args console=ttyS0

Starting install...
Retrieving file .treeinfo...                                                                                                                                                                                          |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file content...                                                                                                                                                                                            |    0 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file info...                                                                                                                                                                                               |   67 B  00:00:00
Retrieving file vmlinuz...                                                                                                                                                                                            | 6.8 MB  00:00:00
Retrieving file initrd.gz...                                                                                                                                                                                          |  14 MB  00:00:00
^CDomain install interrupted.
Installation aborted at user request
ziggidy@zeus:~/ISOs$
```

Comment: For 18.10 and 18.04 your are using the live installer. Try the [alternate installer](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04.1/release/?_ga=2.152233019.306382925.1545495149-1242362650.1246318765), which would be the same as what you used to use.

Comment: Thank you Doug, you are a beautiful person!! That did the trick. I thought perhaps they just changed the naming convention on the ISO. I'm not entirely certain what a live installer is.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Couldn't find hvm kernel for Ubuntu tree](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1116383/couldnt-find-hvm-kernel-for-ubuntu-tree)

Comment: Consider posting and accepting an answer, please; for fellow people to find the answer quickly.